# Odoo 14.0 cannot make public route

Tags: request, public, odoo-14

How can I create a public route to access stock data without login authentication?

@http.route('/nuanju/stock_report', auth='public', website=True, methods=['GET'])
For this request, I'm getting this error :

odoo.exceptions.AccessError: You are not allowed to access 'Quants' (stock.quant) records.

This operation is allowed for the following groups:

```
- Inventory/Administrator

- Inventory/User

- User types/Internal User
```

Contact your administrator to request access if necessary.

I have also one public user in database

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved by accessing data with sudo

request.env['stock.quant'].sudo().search([])

instead of

request.env['stock.quant'].search([])